# Octave/matlab, multiple default arguments defined by constant

Tags: matlab, arguments, constants, default-arguments

I have a problem with defining default arguments to a function in Octave/Matlab by a previously defined constant. Could someone give me a hint, why in the following code `test1(1)` displays `1` and `100`, while `test2(1)` fails with `error:`testarg' undefined near line 1 column 36`? Thank you so much!

```
testarg = 100

function test1 (arg1=testarg, arg2=100)
 disp(arg1)
 disp(arg2)
endfunction

function test2 (arg1=testarg, arg2=testarg)
 disp(arg1)
 disp(arg2)
endfunction

test1(1)
test2(2)
```

Edit:

Please not that the order of the arguments matters:

```
function test3 (arg1=100, arg2=testarg)
 disp(arg1)
 disp(arg2)
endfunction

 octave:8> test1(1)
 1
 100
 octave:9>test3(1)
 error: `testarg' undefined near line 1 column 32
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? which results do you want to get for these functions? What actually do you get?

Comment: Sorry if I was not precise; the second call claims testarg to be undefined. I edited my question :)

Comment: maybe `test2` expects to get two variables? In `test1` you defined the second veriable, so it have no problems with that...

Comment: But would it then not complain about `arg2` rather than `testarg`? Please note my other edit. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that syntax in Matlab, is it an Octave thing? In general default arguments need to be a constant rather than some other variable that may or may not be in scope or initialised at the time the function is called (feel free to educate me on languages where this isn't the case, of course).

The 'normal' way to do default arguments in regular Matlab is like this:

```
function test1(arg1, arg2)
    if nargin < 2
        arg2 = 100;
    end
    if nargin < 1
        arg2 = testarg;     % if testarg isn't in scope this still won't work
    end
    disp(arg1);
    disp(arg2);
end
```

Comment: yes only Octave allows default arguments, MATLAB doesnt: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Default-Arguments.html. Plus Octave allows to define functions inline, in which case it creates a closure (it's like defining an anonymous function which accesses variables in the outer scope). Of course such "inline functions" are also not allowed in MATLAB, only the usual `test1 = @(arg1,arg2) ...` syntax is permitted

Comment: @Amro Good to know, thanks. Seems I wasn't wrong about them needing to be constants, thankfully :D

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug to me, you should [report it](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/bugs.html) to the Octave developers.

In the meanwhile, here is a workaround:

```
testarg = 100

function test1 (arg1, arg2)
 if nargin < 2, arg2 = 100; end
 if nargin < 1, arg1 = testarg; end

 disp(arg1)
 disp(arg2)
endfunction

test1(2)
```

That said, it is better to be explicit here, and define them as "global variables". If the `testarg` is intended as a constant, better make it a function that returns said value:

```
testarg = @() 100;
```